# What is the name of this circuit which has Vout = sin(Vin) transfer function?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design, transfer-function

[image: img]

I found this on IEEE's page: https://sscs.ieee.org/education/2017-2018-circuit-analysis-design-contest

Is there a name for this circuit or even does this circuit exist? If so, why and what is the circuit structure?

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a design contest if it already had a name and you could look it up on the web.

Comment: Something which adds is an add-er, subtract is a subtract-er/-or. Multiply : multiply-er (Which in English becomes -ier). So following that logic, this must be a Sinus-er or a Sinus-or.

Comment: @Chu: Not necessarily.  A contest could be about extreme specs for a common function.  See Google's contest for small and efficient inverter as example.  You could have a contest for something as simple as a buck converter to make 5 V at 1 A from 24 V, with the distinguishing characteristic being the highest efficiency wins.  A contest does not mean obscure requirements by itself.

Comment: could call ir a "sinner"

Comment: Note that you made this requirement up yourself. Nowhere does the contest mention that it must be a sin(x) function. On the contrary, it is specifically mention: _The characteristic need not be a sinusoidal function._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a Folding Amplifier. You just need to tack on an opamp to get the 1V swing. [See here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3915708_Current_mirror_based_folding_amplifier).

Answer (score 1):

This circuit doesn't have a standard or common name.  These requirements are highly unusual.  This has therefore been done so rarely, if at all, that no common name for this circuit has evolved.

Comment: Just curious, how would you approach such a problem statement? From zero to first peak, I can assume an op-amp but what then?

Comment: @Whis: That's for the contestants to figure out.  No, I'm not going to give any ideas.

Comment: @ whiskeyjack, well no. the competition requires operation from a 1V supply,  if any supply was allowed then yeah comparators that enable adding or subtracting from the input at each corner voltage.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Since the contest is over can give a hint? I've built a circuit that does this function but it was huge and noisy. I don't think the solution to this problem is what I built.